# How can I do logging in a FastCGI server without slowing it down

Tags: iis, fastcgi

I've written a FastCGI server for IIS as a host for the programming language PowerBuilder.

I'd like to add logging to the C++ code but I don't want to slow down the PowerBuilder requests.

I'd like suggestions on logging options.

Comment: Literally this question equals to "how can I write a high performance logging framework", or "what high performance logging framework to use", so many will vote to close it. Things you might consider are already out there, such as Windows ETW, which is widely used in Windows components, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/about-event-tracing

Comment: Thanks for the tip about event tracing. The biggest problem with stackoverflow is that many people are more concerned with the wording of the question instead of providing an answer.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: If there were a place to mark a comment as 'the answer', I would.